U-Net Accuracy is not increasing
I have implemented a U-Net model to perform self supervised learning on images (spectrograms; dim=(376, 128)) to learn background/foreground masks. I am very new to self supervised learning but after reading all the related research papers I have created this approach:

Generate spectrograms from audio files (they are the ground truth)

Mask random sections of spectrograms (input images) and input it into the network

Make the network recreate the ground truth image
Output of the network is a binary mask of background

The process aims to deniose the image/audio by classifying each pixel as 0 or 1 (where 0 should be background) but the accuracy is constant at 0.4014 even though the loss is reducing:
Epoch 1:
6/12992 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 5:21 25ms/step - accuracy: 0.4014 - loss: 6178.7236
12992/12992 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 655s 50ms/step - accuracy: 0.4014 - loss: 42.1142 - val_accuracy: 0.4014 - val_loss: 0.6232
Epoch 2:
12992/12992 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 435s 33ms/step - accuracy: 0.4014 - loss: 0.6232 - val_accuracy: 0.4014 - val_loss: 0.6232
Epoch 3:
12992/12992 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 217s 17ms/step - accuracy: 0.4014 - loss: 0.6231 - val_accuracy: 0.4014 - val_loss: 0.6232
It is the same even after 10 epochs.
This is how I am creating the model:
def get_small_compact_unet(img_dims=(None, None, 3)):
"""
This is the modification of the U-Net architecture
It has 2 downsampling and 2 upsampling layers but with the lesser number of filters in each layer
"""
n_filters = [16, 32, 64]
left_output_dims = calculate_left_dims(img_dims, n_filters)
print('left_output_dims:', left_output_dims)
right_output_dims = calculate_right_dims(left_output_dims[-1], n_filters[::-1])
print('right_output_dims:', right_output_dims)
# inputs
inputs = layers.Input(shape=img_dims)
print(tf.config.experimental.get_memory_usage("GPU:0"))
# encoder: contracting path - downsample
# 1 - downsample
f1, p1 = downsample_block(inputs, 16)
print(tf.config.experimental.get_memory_usage("GPU:0"))
# 2 - downsample
f2, p2 = downsample_block(p1, 32)
print(tf.config.experimental.get_memory_usage("GPU:0"))

# 3 - bottleneck
bottleneck = double_conv_block(p2, 64)
print(tf.config.experimental.get_memory_usage("GPU:0"))

# decoder: expanding path - upsample
# 4 - upsample
u8 = upsample_block(bottleneck, f2, 32)
print(tf.config.experimental.get_memory_usage("GPU:0"))
# 5 - upsample
u9 = upsample_block(u8, f1, 16)
print(tf.config.experimental.get_memory_usage("GPU:0"))

# outputs - background / foreground mask layers
outputs = layers.Conv2D(1, 1, padding="same", activation="softmax")(u9)
print(tf.config.experimental.get_memory_usage("GPU:0"))

# unet model with Keras Functional API
unet_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs, name="Small-Compact-U-Net")

return unet_model

callbacks = [
    tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("spectrogram_segmentation.keras", save_best_only=True)
]
model = get_small_compact_unet()
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-2),
                  loss="binary_crossentropy",
                  metrics=["accuracy"], 
             )
model_history = model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    validation_data=valid_dataset,
    batch_size=1,
    epochs=50,
    callbacks=callbacks,
    verbose=1
)

This is the compiled model param details:

Total params: 2,067,649 (7.89 MB)


Trainable params: 2,067,649 (7.89 MB)


Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 B)

The accuracy does not change even when I reduce the learning rate even though the loss starts off smaller and does keep reducing slowly.
When I increase the learning rate the initial loss is very high and it does keep reducing but the accuracy is the same- 0.414.
I'm not really sure why this model is stuck.
Edit: Also, I was wondering if the accuracy or even IoU metric with binary_crossentropy loss makes sense for this problem?

I'm not sure I understand why a U-Net trained to do image inpainting would be good at classifying background/foreground. Those seem like very different tasks. e.g. The model might think that a signal contains a loud noise at a specific frequency, and so output a 1, but that might be a background noise. How is the model supposed to "know" that it is switching from predicting loudness to predicting foreground/background? Can you explain your thinking here?

@NickODell I get what you're saying. The process is flawed. I have changed my approach but I am still facing the same problem. I am editing the question to reflect my new approach.

Hi, I have reviewed your code. The issue seems to be that the loss value is
not decreasing. I have seen that you're using upsampling and downsampling,
but skip connections are not there in the code. Use skip
connections.If possible, you can try using a pretrained U-Net model to
improve performance.Use optimization techniques such as keras tuner for
optimizing the model for better performance
